# Get city place id from Google Places API

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-api, google-places

My app has a search for cities, but when the user enters the full address, he gets `placeId` that is more specific than a city -- for an address, or a business. I want the `placeId` for the city to store in my database.

I'm using Geocomplete http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/

```
$('input[name="address"]').geocomplete().bind('geocode:result', function(event, result){
    console.log(result.place_id)
});
```

I need to get `place_id` city from `place_id` address and check validity in PHP.

Comment: It's the 'comma on the third line'- issue again.

Comment: Please share your code, and tell exactly it's PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: @OlegAndreyev I've updated the question

Comment: Minor edits for legibility.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on documentation of [geocomplete](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/), event `geocode:result` will be triggered with result described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?csw=1#GeocodingResults), you need to look in `address_components` which is described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?csw=1#GeocodingAddressTypes) and use one of `administrative_area` fields

Comment: `address_components` does not have `place_id` for city, only city name. There are plenty of cities with the same name all over the world

Comment: To get place_id you need to fetch Place Details https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid results that represent full addresses by using `types` to `(regions)` or `(cities)`, see details [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete).

Whether to use one or the other will depend on which countries you want results from, because sometimes cities can be `administrative_area1` (e.g. Tokyo), see the note in the [Place Autocomplete Address Form](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) example.